# When using the AWS PHP SDK 3.x is there a way to batch-upload multipart files to S3 in parallel using a getCommand array?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-php-sdk

I am working on a process to upload a large number of files to S3, and for my smaller files I am building a list of commands using getCommand to upload them concurrently, like this:

```
$commands = array();
$commands[] = $s3Client->getCommand('PutObject', array(
    'Bucket' => 'mybucket',
    'Key'    => 'filename.ext',
    'Body'   => fopen('filepath', 'r'),
));
$commands[] = $s3Client->getCommand('PutObject', array(
    'Bucket' => 'mybucket',
    'Key'    => 'filename_2.ext',
    'Body'   => fopen('filepath_2', 'r'),
));
etc.

try {
    $pool = new CommandPool($s3Client, $commands, [
        'concurrency' => 5,
        'before' => function (CommandInterface $cmd, $iterKey) {
            //Do stuff before the file starts to upload
        },
        'fulfilled' => function (ResultInterface $result, $iterKey, PromiseInterface $aggregatePromise) {
            //Do stuff after the file is finished uploading
        },
        'rejected' => function (AwsException $reason, $iterKey, PromiseInterface $aggregatePromise) {
            //Do stuff if the file fails to upload
        },
    ]);

    // Initiate the pool transfers
    $promise = $pool->promise();

    // Force the pool to complete synchronously
    $promise->wait();

    $promise->then(function() { echo "All the files have finished uploading!"; });
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Exception Thrown: Failed to upload: ".$e->getMessage()."<br>\n";
}
```

This works fine for the smaller files, but some of my files are large enough that I'd like them to automatically be uploaded in multiple parts. So, instead of using `getCommand('PutObject')`, which uploads an entire file, I'd like to use something like `getCommand('ObjectUploader')` so that the larger files can be automatically broken up as needed. However, when I try to use `getCommand('ObjectUploader')` it throws an error and says that it doesn't know what to do with that.  I'm guessing that perhaps the command has a different name, which is why it is throwing the error. But, it's also possible that it's not possible to do it like this.

If you've worked on something like this in the past, how have you done it? Or even if you haven't worked on it, I'm open to any ideas you might have.

Thanks!

References:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_commands.html#command-pool
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-multipart-upload.html#object-uploader

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go a different direction with this, and instead of using an array of concurrent commands I am now using a set of concurrent MultipartUploader promises, as shown in an example on this page: https://500.keboola.com/parallel-multipart-uploads-to-s3-in-php-61ff03ffc043

Here are the basics:

```
//Create an array of your file paths
$files = ['file1', 'file2', ...];

//Create an array to hold the promises
$promises = [];

//Create MultipartUploader objects, and add them to the promises array
foreach($files as $filePath) {
  $uploader = new \Aws\S3\MultipartUploader($s3Client, $filePath, $uploaderOptions);
  $promises[$filePath] = $uploader->promise();
}

//Process the promises once they are all complete
$results = \GuzzleHttp\Promise\unwrap($promises);
```